# Python error: "LookupError: no codec search functions registered: can't find encoding"

Tags: python, canopy

I'm running Enthough Canope python distribution in Windows 7 and cannot run working python in a command line.  'python' brings up:

```
Python 2.7.3 |CUSTOM| (default, Aug  8 2013, 05:30:12) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

but any python command yields:

```
>>> x = 5
LookupError: no codec search functions registered: can't find encoding
```

Any idea why this is happening?  I can run ipython perfectly well, but I'm concerned that inability to run basic python is preventing other functionality such as installing new packages.  Grateful for assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you make Canopy User Python your default python? My guess is you didn't. Doing so will invoke Canopy's User python executable from the command line and `x=5` should work. Another way to achieve the same is to open a "Canopy Command Prompt" window from the Windows Start menu: that will only make Canopy your default python for that session. To access it, `Start > All programs > Enthought Canopy > Canopy Command Prompt`

One way or another, when you start Canopy's `python` from the terminal you should see:

```
C:\Users\jrocher\> python
Enthought Canopy Python 2.7.3 | 32-bit | (default, Dec  2 2013, 16:14:17) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks you set me on the right track.  My path was set to the wrong folder: I'd added `..\Enthought\Canopy\App` (which does include a python executable, but not the correct one) but it should've been `..\Enthought\Canopy\System\Scripts`

Comment: Geotheory, no, the System path that you describe is still incorrect! It should be "User" where you have "System". Please see this article: https://support.enthought.com/entries/23646538-Make-Canopy-User-Python-be-your-default-Python